# Missing first character of fields in csv

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I'm working on a csv import script in php. It works fine, except for foreign characters in the beginning of a field.

The code looks like this

```
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
         $teljing[] = $data;

     fclose($handle);
}
```

Here is a data example showing my issue

```
føroyskir stavir, "Kr. 201,50"
óvirkin ting, "Kr. 100,00"
```

This will result in the following

```
array 
(
     [0] => array 
          (
                 [0] => 'føroyskir stavir',
                 [1] => 'Kr. 201,50'
          )
     [1] => array 
          (
                 [0] => 'virkin ting', <--- Should be 'óvirkin ting'
                 [1] => 'Kr. 100,00'
          )
)
```

I have seen this behaivior documented in some comments in php.net, and I have tried `ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);` to detect line endings. No success.

Anyone familiar with this issue?

Edit:

Thanks you AJ, this issue is now solved.

`setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');`

Was the solution.

Comment: what happens if you call `fopen($filename, "rb")`

Comment: @AJ Exactly the same - I cannot see any difference in the results

Comment: from the PHP manual for fgetcsv():  "Note: Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If LANG is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this function."

Comment: @AJ - Using `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');` worked. Thank you.

Comment: glad it worked, I'll post below as answer.

Comment: @Ragnar123 I'm using Japanese language in CSV import. Faced the same issue: for some strings, first character is truncated. Original string is: **商品管理番号（商品URL）** I tried with `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja_JP');`

But it shows: **品管理番号（商品url）**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/fgetcsv) for `fgetcsv()`:

"Note: Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If LANG is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this function."

Comment: @Ragnar123
I'm using Japanese language in CSV import.
Faced the same issue: for some strings, first character is truncated.

Original string is: **商品管理番号（商品URL）**

I tried with
`setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja_JP');`

But it shows: **品管理番号（商品url）**

Answer (score 0):

Copied from the PHP.net/fgetcsv comments:

> **kent at marketruler dot com**
>   04-Feb-2010 11:18 Note that fgetcsv,
>   at least in PHP 5.3 or previous, will
>   NOT work with UTF-16 encoded files.
>   Your options are to convert the entire
>   file to ISO-8859-1 (or latin1), or
>   convert line by line and convert each
>   line into ISO-8859-1 encoding, then
>   use str_getcsv (or compatible
>   backwards-compatible implementation).
>   If you need to read non-latin
>   alphabets, probably best to convert to
>   UTF-8.
>
> See str_getcsv for a
>   backwards-compatible version of it
>   with PHP < 5.3, and see utf8_decode
>   for a function written by Rasmus
>   Andersson which provides utf16_decode.
>   The modification I added was that the
>   BOP appears at the top of the file,
>   then not on subsequent lines. So you
>   need to store the endian-ness, and
>   then re-send it upon each subsequent
>   line decoding. This modified version
>   returns the endianness, if it's not
>   available:

```
<?php
/**
 * Decode UTF-16 encoded strings.
 *
 * Can handle both BOM'ed data and un-BOM'ed data.
 * Assumes Big-Endian byte order if no BOM is available.
 * From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php
 *
 * @param   string  $str  UTF-16 encoded data to decode.
 * @return  string  UTF-8 / ISO encoded data.
 * @access  public
 * @version 0.1 / 2005-01-19
 * @author  Rasmus Andersson {@link http://rasmusandersson.se/}
 * @package Groupies
 */
function utf16_decode($str, &$be=null) {
    if (strlen($str) < 2) {
        return $str;
    }
    $c0 = ord($str{0});
    $c1 = ord($str{1});
    $start = 0;
    if ($c0 == 0xFE && $c1 == 0xFF) {
        $be = true;
        $start = 2;
    } else if ($c0 == 0xFF && $c1 == 0xFE) {
        $start = 2;
        $be = false;
    }
    if ($be === null) {
        $be = true;
    }
    $len = strlen($str);
    $newstr = '';
    for ($i = $start; $i < $len; $i += 2) {
        if ($be) {
            $val = ord($str{$i})   << 4;
            $val += ord($str{$i+1});
        } else {
            $val = ord($str{$i+1}) << 4;
            $val += ord($str{$i});
        }
        $newstr .= ($val == 0x228) ? "\n" : chr($val);
    }
    return $newstr;
}
?>

Trying the "setlocale" trick did not work for me, e.g.

<?php
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en.UTF16");
$line = fgetcsv($file, ...)
?>
```

> But that's perhaps because my platform
>   didn't support it. However, fgetcsv
>   only supports single characters for
>   the delimiter, etc. and complains if
>   you pass in a UTF-16 version of said
>   character, so I gave up on that rather
>   quickly.
>
> Hope this is helpful to someone out
>   there.