# First letter disappear if it has an accent (CSV file, UTF-8 encoded)

Tags: php, zend-framework, csv, utf-8

I'm actually working on a web application coded in php with zend framework. I need to translate every pages in french and english so I use csv file to do it.

My problem is when a word start with an accentued letter like É or À, the letter just disappear, but the rest of the word is displayed.

For example, if my csv file contains `Écriture`, it displays `criture`. But if I have `exécution`, it displays `exécution` without any problems.

Everytime I want to display text in my view, I just call `<?php echo $this->translate('line to call in csv'); ?>`  and my text is displayed.

Like I said ,my application is encoded with UTF-8, and I don't have any problems withs specials characters, except when they're first. I googled it but couldn't find anything for now.

Thanks already for your help !

**UPDATE**

I forgot to say that when I execute my application in zend browser to debug it, everything's fine, my É displays. It's only in broswers like IE or FF that I have the problem.

**UPDATE #2**

I just found another post talking about fgetcsv, and it looks like the function I use to translate from my csv file is using fgetcsv() ... could it be the problem ? And if it is, how can I fix it ? It's coded like that in Zend Translate library I'm not sure I want to start changing things there ...

**UPDATE #3**

I continued my research and I found issues in PHP when encoded UTF-8. But Zend Framework is encoded UTF-8 by default so I'm sure there is a way to make this work.. I'm still searching but I hope someone has the solution !

Comment: Show the `::translate` method. Do you define the encoding via the HTTP protocol?

Comment: @Dor , I use the translate method of my view, I didnt code it and I'm not even sure where it is. I found one in Zend/Translate/Adapter.php, but like I said I'm not sure it the one I use. All I know is that when I'm in my view, I call it like that `$this->translate(messageId)`. Do you need the method I found in Adapter.php ?

Comment: For the encoding via HTTP protocol, I can't tell for sure how it's done. I have this in my layout.phtml `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` is that it ?

Comment: Then I guess the `translate` method is not important. The HTML code you show here is equivalent to the HTTP header that should be sent (before outputting any data to the browser) with PHP's header() function. It's a lot better to set the encoding via the HTTP protocol than with meta tags. Are all your **files** UTF-8 encoded? Edit: Make sure that your framework knows that your text is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @Dor, I don't know how to do it another way than how it's done, this part was already done when I started working on this application. I think that all my files are encoded  UTF-8, I only have two .csv files, en.csv and fr.csv and they are ... And as far as I know my views are too, but how can I be sure ? And how can I make sure my framework knows the encoding type ? I tried to add $this->view->setEncoding('UTF-8') at a few places, but didn't change anything. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I just did a test, I added `echo $this->view->getEncoding();`to see how was encoded my view. It returned UTF-8 like it's supposed to. I tried it on two different pages and it returned the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, I tried AJ's solution and it worked: 
[Missing first character of fields in csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756373/missing-first-character-of-fields-in-csv)

The problem seems to be that fgetcsv() uses locale settings, just use

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

Comment: I tried that, but maybe I didnt put it at the right place because it didnt work :( Where did you put it ? In your controller ? Or your bootstrap maybe ? (Thanks for your answer ! )

Comment: I tried again, wrote it first line of my `_initLocale()` function, and it worked ! It doesn't work if I change en_US for fr_CA or en_CA, but it works well with en_US. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

```
In .csv file content try to use
; as delimiter 
  and 
" as enclosure.
something like this inside .csv file
```

### "key1";"value1" ##`first line`

### "key1";"value1" ##`second line`

### "key1";"value1" ##`fird line`

this solve like ussue for me

Answer (score 0):

view csv file using hex editor and make sure it is encoded in the right way

"É" is `0xC3 0x89`,
"À" is `0xC3 0x80`

Comment: I opened in in UltraEdit and it looks okay, my É is C3 89

Answer (score 0):

Did you have some `strtoupper()` or `ucfirst()` or similar functions in your code? In that case try `mb_strtoupper($str,  'UTF-8')`

Comment: No I don't have any of these function